# How to tell whether *os.File returned by Go argparse is initialized

Tags: go, pointers

I have a `golang` project using [argparse](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/akamensky/argparse) which takes a not required file as argument. The file is retrieved with [File flag](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/akamensky/argparse#Command.File) which may be allocating some memory for a file. code :

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/akamensky/argparse"
)

func main() {
    parser := argparse.NewParser("", "")

    myFile := parser.File("", "file", os.O_RDONLY, 0444, &argparse.Options{Required: false})

    if err := parser.Parse(os.Args); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error at parsing: %v", err)
    }

    if myFile != nil {
        fmt.Println(myFile)
        myFile.Stat()
    }
}
```

When I run my command, my output is

```
&{<nil>}
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Saying I'm dereferencing a `nil` pointer but when I check whether the pointer is `nil` or not it says it is not although the `Println` returns a pointer with nil value.
How can I check if the content of my file pointer is `nil` or not ?

*NB: the error comes from myFile.Stat()*

Comment: You should start by examining the error returned by `parser.Parse`. If that doesn't work, show a minimal reproducible example and a stacktrace with line numbers.

Comment: `parser.Parse` doesn't return any eror the error come from `myFile.Stat()`

Comment: It can, and you're ignoring it. Again, we need a reproducible example.

Comment: added it, it was just missing in this code not in the original

Comment: When people ask for a "reproducible example" they are asking for something they can copy, paste, and run to reproduce the problem. I've added the missing bits to your question because I'm interested in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are using provides a function for checking this. You need to do:

```
if !argparse.IsNilFile(myFile) {
    fmt.Println(myFile)
    myFile.Stat()
}
```

This is necessary because the `File` function returns a pointer to an empty `os.File` object, and since you've marked your flag as optional, this object will remain empty without parsing errors if you don't provide your flag at the command line. `Stat` obviously isn't going to work on an empty `os.File` object, and that's why you're getting your invalid memory address.